# How to change the legend title of a ggplot categorized by the factor of a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

So, I have a problem with ggplot2 that seems too trivial, but out of five different approaches, none produced the desired result. I wish to change the legend title of a plot of a continuous variable over the years by the category of a second variable. In that way, if I have three categories in the second variable, I'll have three lines of the continuous variable over the years. I use the mtcars data to try to replicate my intent and problem. So, my code is similar to the following:

```
mt <- ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),linetype=factor(am),y=mpg))
mt <- mt+geom_line(aes(group=factor(am)),size=0.8)
mt <- mt+labs(y='Number of cylinders',x='Mileage per galon',color='Transmission')
```

In this case, my continuous variable is mpg, while my Years variable would be cyl, number of cylinders, and factor variable is am. I tried to change the legend title by using color, inside labs, but that was unfruitful. I tried other options too, which are scale_color_discrete() function, fill, guides() function, scale_fill_discrete() function, also to no avail. So, my intent is to change my legends title. Following, 
[the graph originated by the code above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xrp7.png)

How would anyone go about changing that factor(am) title legend?

Comment: Could you include a sample of your expected plot?

Comment: I'd like to change just the legend title factor(am) to something like Transmission.

Comment: Just use fill argument in labs. `fill="Transmission"`(I hadn't checked it's linetype not fill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mt <- ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),linetype=factor(am),y=mpg))
mt <- mt+geom_line(aes(group=factor(am)),size=0.8)
mt <- mt+labs(y='Number of cylinders',x='Mileage per galon', linetype='Transmission')
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

Explanation: You used the elements `x`, `y` and `linetype` but then tried to assign a string to the legend for `color` which you **didn't** use. That's why it had no effect. Changing the parameter to `linetype` solves this.